# How to extract variables from an auxiliary file?

Tags: footnotes, auxiliary-files, write

I would like to use an auxiliary file to read and write some information.

---

### Context

In this case, I am using this auxiliary file to record the widths used in the footnote formatting.
Indeed, I want my footnote numbers to be right-aligned, like this :

[image]

So I need to know **in advance** (using information from previous compilations) the width of the widest footnote number (`\@widthFootnoteNum` for a "normal" footnote, `\@mpwidthFootnoteNum` for a footnote in a minipage).

If I only take into account "normal" footnotes, I have no particular problem. The value of `\@widthFootnoteNum` is written in an auxiliary file (called `\jobname.foot`) at the end of the compilation and read at the beginning of the next compilation.

However, if I do the same thing with footnotes in a minipage environment, things get complicated. Several values are written to the auxiliary file and I have to read this file to find the correct widths and write to it to give the correct widths for the next compilation in parallel.

My tests are not conclusive...
I manage to write all the necessary information, but I can't read it afterwards.

---

### MWE

Consider the following MWE:
A simple file containing 20 "normal" footnotes and two `minipage` environments containing 2 and 7 notes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers={Proportional}]{LibertinusSerif}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@symbolesnum[1]{% new numerotation for minipage footnote
    \ifcase#1\unskip \or \unskip * \or \unskip † \or \unskip ‡ \or \unskip ** \or \unskip †† \or \unskip ‡‡ \or \unskip *** \or \unskip ††† \or \unskip ‡‡‡ \or \unskip **** \or \unskip †††† \or \unskip ‡‡‡‡ \or \unskip ***** \or \unskip ††††† \or \unskip ‡‡‡‡‡ \else\@ctrerr \fi%
}

\newlength{\@widthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp} % width of the current footer number
\newlength{\@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp} % maximum footnote number width
\newlength{\@widthFootnoteNum} % width set after reading the auxiliary file 

\AtBeginDocument{% Creating and opening the auxiliary file
    \newwrite\auxFootnoteOutput% 
    \immediate\openout\auxFootnoteOutput=\jobname.foot%
    \setlength{\@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp}{0pt}%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
    \immediate\write\auxFootnoteOutput{\the\@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp}% Writing the value of \@widthFootnoteNum
    \immediate\closeout\auxFootnoteOutput% Closing the auxiliary file
}

% For each footnote, the width of the footnote number is measured by \@widthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp. 
% This width is compared to \@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp. 
% If \@widthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp is greater than \@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp then \@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp will take the value of \@widthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp. 
% Thus, the width \@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp corresponds to the width of the widest footnote number.

\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{% 
    \settowidth{\@widthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp}{{\footnotesize\liningnums{\@thefnmark}}}%
    \ifdim \@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp < \@widthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp%
        \global\setlength{\@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp}{\@widthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp}%
    \fi%
    \makebox[\@widthFootnoteNum][r]{\liningnums{\@thefnmark}}.\enspace% right aligned footnote number using "\@widthFootnoteNum"
    #1%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Idem for minipage :
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newlength{\@mpwidthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp}
\newlength{\@mpmaxWidthFootnoteNumTemp}
\newlength{\@mpwidthFootnoteNum}

\def\thempfootnote{\@symbolesnum{\c@mpfootnote}}

\AtBeginEnvironment{minipage}{%
    \setlength{\@mpmaxWidthFootnoteNumTemp}{0pt}%
    %
    \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
        \settowidth{\@mpwidthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp}{{\footnotesize\liningnums{\@thefnmark}}}%
        \ifdim \@mpmaxWidthFootnoteNumTemp < \@mpwidthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp%
            \global\setlength{\@mpmaxWidthFootnoteNumTemp}{\@mpwidthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp}%
        \fi%
        \makebox[\@mpwidthFootnoteNum][r]{\liningnums{\@thefnmark}}\enspace% right aligned footnote number using the value of "\@mpwidthFootnoteNum" for this particular minipage
        #1%
    }
}

\AtEndEnvironment{minipage}{% write the maximum width for the current mini-page
    \immediate\write\auxFootnoteOutput{\the\@mpmaxWidthFootnoteNumTemp}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\footnote{A footnote.}, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ornare, risus sit amet lacinia lacinia, lacus erat tristique est, et consequat nunc dolor id lorem. Suspendisse lobortis, metus vitae semper volutpat, nulla metus mollis tortor, non finibus sem quam id mauris\footnote{A footnote.}. Fusce ut velit ac magna aliquet ullamcorper vitae nec massa. Nunc suscipit ipsum tortor, sed facilisis nisi ultrices finibus. Cras efficitur felis felis, sit amet aliquam dolor posuere et. Curabitur ut condimentum lorem. Etiam ac nisi augue. Nullam congue purus et metus fringilla malesuada. Praesent faucibus fermentum mi eget fringilla. Morbi velit ipsum, lacinia sed dolor id, fermentum auctor velit\footnote{A footnote.}. Donec quis ante eget enim tempor ultrices.

Pellentesque ultrices efficitur ipsum ut bibendum. Sed ut vestibulum mi. Sed neque neque, efficitur nec sem eget, pulvinar ultricies lectus. Nam ullamcorper dolor sed nulla ultricies varius. Donec mattis cursus dolor eu vehicula. Fusce molestie at ipsum vel commodo\footnote{A footnote.}. Vivamus eu malesuada metus. Praesent sed cursus ex. Fusce justo eros, elementum quis libero et, vestibulum pretium tortor. In rhoncus ex eu posuere placerat. Aenean fringilla sem a nisi aliquet egestas\footnote{A footnote.}. Fusce vestibulum leo nibh, vel sollicitudin mauris interdum sed.

Curabitur tincidunt augue et rutrum laoreet. Morbi pharetra lacus ac mi finibus condimentum. Nunc id venenatis neque. Fusce sed purus quis magna accumsan euismod a ac augue. Integer venenatis vulputate lacus, vel dapibus augue hendrerit sed\footnote{A footnote.}. Donec eget mattis arcu, nec hendrerit ante. Donec rutrum est ut massa blandit, id semper metus tincidunt. Suspendisse nec vulputate risus, nec efficitur ex. Donec condimentum risus ligula, at consectetur erat lacinia sed. Aenean vel euismod purus. Vestibulum interdum neque vitae erat rhoncus fermentum. Aenean convallis nisl velit, sit amet volutpat dui vulputate a.

Sed nec augue pellentesque, commodo diam quis, vehicula libero\footnote{A footnote.}. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus tincidunt ligula vitae arcu tempor, eu facilisis augue fringilla. Curabitur id pulvinar ipsum, et gravida nisl. Aenean eget faucibus dolor, vel fermentum metus\footnote{A footnote.}. Quisque risus purus, porta vel eleifend nec, tempus sit amet diam. Sed sit amet commodo odio. Curabitur in tempor lorem. Sed venenatis malesuada odio, ac scelerisque nisi finibus ac. Aliquam cursus aliquet eleifend.

Duis in nisi vitae augue lacinia sodales sed vel libero. Duis vehicula, justo commodo ultrices blandit, purus sem ultrices velit, in imperdiet ligula sem vel sem\footnote{A footnote.}. Nam diam turpis, pulvinar ac lorem at, sagittis cursus nibh. Sed id gravida enim, id rutrum felis. Nam aliquet leo vel venenatis volutpat. Integer laoreet tincidunt mi, in faucibus nunc. Fusce porta et lorem id consectetur. Praesent ac vehicula metus, quis hendrerit tellus\footnote{A footnote.}. Maecenas consequat eleifend ante, non vehicula risus aliquet vitae. Duis et velit elit. Mauris nec lorem vel lorem rhoncus congue vitae in arcu.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\footnote{A footnote.}, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ornare, risus sit amet lacinia lacinia, lacus erat tristique est, et consequat nunc dolor id lorem. Suspendisse lobortis, metus vitae semper volutpat, nulla metus mollis tortor, non finibus sem quam id mauris\footnote{A footnote.}. Fusce ut velit ac magna aliquet ullamcorper vitae nec massa. Nunc suscipit ipsum tortor, sed facilisis nisi ultrices finibus. Cras efficitur felis felis, sit amet aliquam dolor posuere et. Curabitur ut condimentum lorem. Etiam ac nisi augue. Nullam congue purus et metus fringilla malesuada. Praesent faucibus fermentum mi eget fringilla. Morbi velit ipsum, lacinia sed dolor id, fermentum auctor velit\footnote{A footnote.}. Donec quis ante eget enim tempor ultrices.

Pellentesque ultrices efficitur ipsum ut bibendum. Sed ut vestibulum mi. Sed neque neque, efficitur nec sem eget, pulvinar ultricies lectus. Nam ullamcorper dolor sed nulla ultricies varius. Donec mattis cursus dolor eu vehicula. Fusce molestie at ipsum vel commodo\footnote{A footnote.}. Vivamus eu malesuada metus. Praesent sed cursus ex. Fusce justo eros, elementum quis libero et, vestibulum pretium tortor. In rhoncus ex eu posuere placerat. Aenean fringilla sem a nisi aliquet egestas\footnote{A footnote.}. Fusce vestibulum leo nibh, vel sollicitudin mauris interdum sed.

Curabitur tincidunt augue et rutrum laoreet. Morbi pharetra lacus ac mi finibus condimentum. Nunc id venenatis neque. Fusce sed purus quis magna accumsan euismod a ac augue. Integer venenatis vulputate lacus, vel dapibus augue hendrerit sed\footnote{A footnote.}. Donec eget mattis arcu, nec hendrerit ante. Donec rutrum est ut massa blandit, id semper metus tincidunt. Suspendisse nec vulputate risus, nec efficitur ex. Donec condimentum risus ligula, at consectetur erat lacinia sed. Aenean vel euismod purus. Vestibulum interdum neque vitae erat rhoncus fermentum. Aenean convallis nisl velit, sit amet volutpat dui vulputate a.

Sed nec augue pellentesque, commodo diam quis, vehicula libero\footnote{A footnote.}. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus tincidunt ligula vitae arcu tempor, eu facilisis augue fringilla. Curabitur id pulvinar ipsum, et gravida nisl. Aenean eget faucibus dolor, vel fermentum metus\footnote{A footnote.}. Quisque risus purus, porta vel eleifend nec, tempus sit amet diam. Sed sit amet commodo odio. Curabitur in tempor lorem. Sed venenatis malesuada odio, ac scelerisque nisi finibus ac. Aliquam cursus aliquet eleifend.

Duis in nisi vitae augue lacinia sodales sed vel libero. Duis vehicula, justo commodo ultrices blandit, purus sem ultrices velit, in imperdiet ligula sem vel sem\footnote{A footnote.}. Nam diam turpis, pulvinar ac lorem at, sagittis cursus nibh. Sed id gravida enim, id rutrum felis. Nam aliquet leo vel venenatis volutpat. Integer laoreet tincidunt mi, in faucibus nunc. Fusce porta et lorem id consectetur. Praesent ac vehicula metus, quis hendrerit tellus\footnote{A footnote.}. Maecenas consequat eleifend ante, non vehicula risus aliquet vitae. Duis et velit elit. Mauris nec lorem vel lorem rhoncus congue vitae in arcu.

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ornare, risus sit amet lacinia lacinia, lacus erat tristique est, et consequat nunc dolor id lorem. Suspendisse lobortis, metus vitae semper volutpat, nulla metus mollis tortor, non finibus sem quam id mauris. Fusce ut velit ac magna aliquet ullamcorper vitae nec massa. Nunc suscipit ipsum tortor, sed facilisis nisi ultrices finibus\footnote{A footnote.}. Cras efficitur felis felis, sit amet aliquam dolor posuere et. Curabitur ut condimentum lorem. Etiam ac nisi augue. Nullam congue purus et metus fringilla malesuada. Praesent faucibus fermentum mi eget fringilla. Morbi velit ipsum, lacinia sed dolor id, fermentum auctor velit. Donec quis ante eget enim tempor ultrices.

Pellentesque ultrices efficitur ipsum ut bibendum. Sed ut vestibulum mi. Sed neque neque, efficitur nec sem eget, pulvinar ultricies lectus. Nam ullamcorper dolor sed nulla ultricies varius. Donec mattis cursus dolor eu vehicula. Fusce molestie at ipsum vel commodo\footnote{A footnote.}. Vivamus eu malesuada metus. Praesent sed cursus ex. Fusce justo eros, elementum quis libero et, vestibulum pretium tortor. In rhoncus ex eu posuere placerat. Aenean fringilla sem a nisi aliquet egestas. Fusce vestibulum leo nibh, vel sollicitudin mauris interdum sed.

Curabitur tincidunt augue et rutrum laoreet. Morbi pharetra lacus ac mi finibus condimentum. Nunc id venenatis neque. Fusce sed purus quis magna accumsan euismod a ac augue. Integer venenatis vulputate lacus, vel dapibus augue hendrerit sed. Donec eget mattis arcu, nec hendrerit ante. Donec rutrum est ut massa blandit, id semper metus tincidunt. Suspendisse nec vulputate risus, nec efficitur ex. Donec condimentum risus ligula, at consectetur erat lacinia sed. Aenean vel euismod purus. Vestibulum interdum neque vitae erat rhoncus fermentum. Aenean convallis nisl velit, sit amet volutpat dui vulputate a.
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ornare, risus sit amet lacinia lacinia, lacus erat tristique est, et consequat nunc dolor id lorem. Suspendisse lobortis, metus vitae semper volutpat, nulla metus mollis tortor, non finibus sem quam id mauris. Fusce ut velit ac magna aliquet ullamcorper vitae nec massa\footnote{A footnote.}. Nunc suscipit ipsum tortor, sed facilisis nisi ultrices finibus\footnote{A footnote.}. Cras efficitur felis felis, sit amet aliquam dolor posuere et. Curabitur ut condimentum lorem. Etiam ac nisi augue. Nullam congue purus et metus fringilla malesuada. Praesent faucibus fermentum mi eget fringilla. Morbi velit ipsum, lacinia sed dolor id, fermentum auctor velit. Donec quis ante eget enim tempor ultrices.

Pellentesque ultrices efficitur ipsum ut bibendum. Sed ut vestibulum mi. Sed neque neque, efficitur nec sem eget, pulvinar ultricies lectus\footnote{A footnote.}. Nam ullamcorper dolor sed nulla ultricies varius. Donec mattis cursus dolor eu vehicula. Fusce molestie at ipsum vel commodo\footnote{A footnote.}. Vivamus eu malesuada metus. Praesent sed cursus ex. Fusce justo eros, elementum quis libero et, vestibulum pretium tortor. In rhoncus ex eu posuere placerat. Aenean fringilla sem a nisi aliquet egestas. Fusce vestibulum leo nibh, vel sollicitudin mauris interdum sed.

Curabitur tincidunt augue et rutrum laoreet\footnote{A footnote.}. Morbi pharetra lacus ac mi finibus condimentum. Nunc id venenatis neque. Fusce sed purus quis magna accumsan euismod a ac augue. Integer venenatis vulputate lacus, vel dapibus augue hendrerit sed. Donec eget mattis arcu, nec hendrerit ante. Donec rutrum est ut massa blandit, id semper metus tincidunt. Suspendisse nec vulputate risus, nec efficitur ex. Donec condimentum risus ligula, at consectetur erat lacinia sed\footnote{A footnote.}. Aenean vel euismod purus. Vestibulum interdum neque vitae erat rhoncus fermentum. Aenean convallis nisl velit, sit amet volutpat dui vulputate a\footnote{A footnote.}.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I get the following auxiliary file:

```
6.704pt
11.40799pt
7.752pt
```

The first value is the value of `\@mpwidthFootnoteNum` for the first minipage environment.
The second value is the value of `\@mpwidthFootnoteNum` for the second minipage environment.
The third value corresponds to the value of `\@widthFootnoteNum` for the "normal" footnote.

So I manage to save all the information needed for the next compilation in an auxiliary file.

---

### The issue

The problem is that I can't use these different values when compiling, because the auxiliary file is successively read and written during the same compilation. So the file is overwritten with each new write.

How can we get around this?

---

### What I tried

I thought of storing all the values at the beginning of the compilation in a kind of numbered list from which one could take out the last value to assign it to `\@widthFootnoteNum` and take out the other values to assign them to the different `\@mpwidthFootnoteNum` of the different minpage. The goal is to have to read the auxiliary file only once. But I don't know how to do it.

I tried to use the `arrayjob` package by putting the auxiliary file in an array, but without success.

I also tried to use two auxiliary files. A file *A* would be used to write the various `@widthFootnoteNum` and `@mpwidthFootnoteNum` during compilation. At the start of the next compilation, file *A* would be copied to a file *B*, which would be read in at the time of compilation and would give the values of the `widthFootnoteNum` and `mpwidthFootnoteNum` calculated at the time of the next compilation. Again, I haven't managed to do this, as I can't seem to copy file *A* into file *B*.

Finally, I tried to store the different values that `@mpwidthFootnoteNum` should take in a syntax `ifcase #1 ...` where `#1` represents the number of the `minipage` environment. For each `minipage` environment, `\@mpwidthFootnoteNum` thus takes a different value.

Here is the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers={Proportional}]{LibertinusSerif}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`<=1 \catcode`>=2
\catcode`{=12 \catcode`}=12 \catcode`#=12
\gdef\curlyBracketL<{>
\gdef\curlyBracketR<}>
\gdef\hashtag<#>
\endgroup

\newcommand*\@symbolesnum[1]{% new numerotation for minipage footnote
    \ifcase#1\unskip \or \unskip * \or \unskip † \or \unskip ‡ \or \unskip ** \or \unskip †† \or \unskip ‡‡ \or \unskip *** \or \unskip ††† \or \unskip ‡‡‡ \or \unskip **** \or \unskip †††† \or \unskip ‡‡‡‡ \or \unskip ***** \or \unskip ††††† \or \unskip ‡‡‡‡‡ \else\@ctrerr \fi%
}

\newlength{\@widthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp} % width of the current footer number
\newlength{\@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp} % maximum footnote number width
\newlength{\@widthFootnoteNum} % width set after reading the auxiliary file 

\AtBeginDocument{% Creating and opening the auxiliary file
    \IfFileExists{\jobname.foot}{\input{\jobname.foot}}{}%
    \newwrite\auxFootnoteOutput% 
    \immediate\openout\auxFootnoteOutput=\jobname.foot%
    \immediate\write\auxFootnoteOutput{\unexpanded{\makeatletter}}%
    \immediate\write\auxFootnoteOutput{%
        \unexpanded{\newcommand*{\@mpwidthFootnoteNum}[1]} \curlyBracketL \unexpanded{\ifcase} \hashtag 1 \unexpanded{\unskip}%
    }
    \setlength{\@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp}{0pt}%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
    \immediate\write\auxFootnoteOutput{%
        \unexpanded{\else 1em \fi} \curlyBracketR%
    }%
    \immediate\write\auxFootnoteOutput{\unexpanded{\setlength} { \unexpanded{\@widthFootnoteNum} }{\the\@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp}}% Writing the value of \@widthFootnoteNum
    \immediate\write\auxFootnoteOutput{\unexpanded{\makeatother}}
    \immediate\closeout\auxFootnoteOutput% Closing the auxiliary file
}

% For each footnote, the width of the footnote number is measured by \@widthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp. 
% This width is compared to \@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp. 
% If \@widthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp is greater than \@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp then \@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp will take the value of \@widthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp. 
% Thus, the width \@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp corresponds to the width of the widest footnote number.

\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{% 
    \settowidth{\@widthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp}{{\footnotesize\liningnums{\@thefnmark}}}%
    \ifdim \@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp < \@widthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp%
        \global\setlength{\@maxWidthFootnoteNumTemp}{\@widthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp}%
    \fi%
    \makebox[\@widthFootnoteNum][r]{\liningnums{\@thefnmark}}.\enspace% right aligned footnote number using "\@widthFootnoteNum"
    #1%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Idem for minipage :
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcounter{mpNum}
\setcounter{mpNum}{0}

\newlength{\@mpwidthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp}
\newlength{\@mpmaxWidthFootnoteNumTemp}

\def\thempfootnote{\@symbolesnum{\c@mpfootnote}}

\AtBeginEnvironment{minipage}{%
    \stepcounter{mpNum}%
    \setlength{\@mpmaxWidthFootnoteNumTemp}{0pt}%
    %
    \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
        \settowidth{\@mpwidthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp}{{\footnotesize\liningnums{\@thefnmark}}}%
        \ifdim \@mpmaxWidthFootnoteNumTemp < \@mpwidthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp%
            \global\setlength{\@mpmaxWidthFootnoteNumTemp}{\@mpwidthCurrentFootnoteNumTemp}%
        \fi%
        \makebox[\@mpwidthFootnoteNum{\thempNum}][r]{\liningnums{\@thefnmark}}\enspace% doesn't work. \@mpwidthFootnoteNum is defined in the auxiliary file
        #1%
    }
}

\AtEndEnvironment{minipage}{% write the maximum width for the current mini-page
    \immediate\write\auxFootnoteOutput{%
        \unexpanded{\or \unskip} \the\@mpmaxWidthFootnoteNumTemp%
    }
}
\makeatother
```

This gives the following auxiliary file:

```
\makeatletter 
\newcommand *{\@mpwidthFootnoteNum }[1] {\ifcase  #1 \unskip 
\or \unskip  6.704pt
\or \unskip  11.40799pt
\else 1em \fi  }
\setlength  { \@widthFootnoteNum  }{7.752pt}
\makeatother
```

This seems correct, but when compiling, I have several errors.

---

### Alternative

I tried using the `eqparbox` package as advised by Werner and while it works fine for "normal" footnotes, the problem persists with footnotes in a `minipage` environment, as you can see from the following images:

[image: Problem minipage 1 with eqparbox]
[image: Problem minipage 2 with eqparbox]

Here is the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers={Proportional}]{LibertinusSerif}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@symbolesnum[1]{% new numerotation
    \ifcase#1\unskip \or \unskip * \or \unskip † \or \unskip ‡ \or \unskip ** \or \unskip †† \or \unskip ‡‡ \or \unskip *** \or \unskip ††† \or \unskip ‡‡‡ \or \unskip **** \or \unskip †††† \or \unskip ‡‡‡‡ \or \unskip ***** \or \unskip ††††† \or \unskip ‡‡‡‡‡ \else\@ctrerr \fi%
}

\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{% 
    \eqmakebox[footnote][r]{\liningnums{\@thefnmark}}.\enspace%
    #1%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% For minipage :
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\thempfootnote{\@symbolesnum{\c@mpfootnote}}
\newcounter{mpNum}
\setcounter{mpNum}{0}

\AtBeginEnvironment{minipage}{%
    \stepcounter{mpNum}%
    \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
        \eqmakebox[mpfootnote][r]{\liningnums{\@thefnmark}}\enspace% doesn't work
%       \eqmakebox[mpfootnote\thempNum][r]{\liningnums{\@thefnmark}}\enspace% doesn't work
        #1%
    }%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Without understanding your problem fully, can't you define at least one max-variable instead of processing an .aux file? // E.g. in pseudocode 1) max=0; 2) if width>max : max=width; etc.

Comment: I don't reallyunderstand what you mean. The maximum width is obtained by measuring all the widths of the footnote numbers. At the end of the compilation, this value is written to the auxiliary file. At the beginning of the next compilation, the auxiliary file is read and the value of the maximum width is used to format the footnotes of the current compilation. So this width must be known from the beginning of the compilation, which is the case thanks to the use of an auxiliary file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting stale aux file in a custom package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529181/detecting-stale-aux-file-in-a-custom-package)

Comment: Thanks @teepeemm but this does not solve my problem. The widths written in the auxiliary file are correct (contrary to the link you show me), my problem is more in reading these different values in the auxiliary file to be able to use them during the next compilation.

Comment: As an aside: You could use [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) to extract the maximum width for you, rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: The big idea with the usual aux file is that you don't write a bare number.  You write it as a command: `\maxFootnoteWidthIs{9.40799pt}`.  Then you when the aux file is read in at the beginning/end of the document, you have defined that command.  That automatically reads it in, and you just need to process it.

Comment: @Werner I didn't know about the `eqparbox` package. I have tried using the `eqmakebox` command but I still can't get the footnotes to align properly in a `minipage` environment. See my edit.

Comment: @Teepeemm I did think of this solution but I have a problem naming the commands. `\@widthFootnoteNum` is a single command so there is no problem. But how do I name the different commands `\@mpwidthFootnoteNum` since I can't put a number in the command name? I had thought of using `\ifcase` so that I would only have to define one command `\@mpwidthFootnoteNum` which would give a different value depending on the number of the `minipage` you are in. I haven't tested this solution yet, I will tonight, but it doesn't seem very elegant.

Comment: There are ways to get a number into a command name.  Does this mean that you're trying to have a different width for each minipage?  Your second example doesn't seem to involve writing to a file, just creating some footnotes; is it intended to be a complete example?  Lastly, is there a reason you're writing to a `.foot` file instead of just using the aux file?

Comment: It seems to me that it is not recommended to put numbers in command names, but I could be wrong. Yes, there is a value of `@mpwidthFootnoteNum` for each `minipage` environment since each one can contain a different number of footnotes. My edit was just to use the `eqparbox` package and find a much easier alternative to using an auxiliary file. I could use the aux file, it doesn't matter, but I thought it was simpler to reason with a dedicated auxiliary file at first. If it is possible to do this, directly in the aux file, then there is indeed no need to create an additional file.

Comment: In case you accept my solution, there is no need to pay out the bounty. For some "privileges" on this platform, you need a certain number of reputation points. It doesn't seem to make sense to reduce your score to below hundred, while there is nothing to gain for me by increasing my score.

Comment: @gernot As you wish but your answer would deserve it, it works very well and is well explained. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following solution writes the width of the footnote labels to the aux file, as `\newfnwidth{0}{4.25006pt}`, `\newfnwidth{0}{8.50012pt}`, `\newfnwidth{1}{6.61023pt}` etc, where `0`, `1`, `2` etc identifies whether we are outside of minipages or within the `1`st, `2`nd etc minipage. The maximum of the lengths of footnote labels is computed at the beginning of the document, when processing the aux file. As usual, you have to run LaTeX twice to propagate the information.

Add the following lines to the preamble.

```
\makeatletter
% maximal length of footnote label
% assumes that \idfnwidth is set to a value identifying the context
% (0 = outside minipage, 1,2,3,... inside minipage)
% Depending on \idfnwidth, \maxfnwidth expands to the macro name
% \maxfnwidth-0, \maxfnwidth-1, \maxfnwidth-2, ...
\newcommand\maxfnwidth{\csname maxfnwidth-\idfnwidth\endcsname}

% \ensuredefmaxfnwidth{N}
% set \idfnwidth to N and define the length \maxfnwidth-N (if undefined)
\newcommand\ensuredefmaxfnwidth[1]{%
  \edef\idfnwidth{#1}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\maxfnwidth\relax
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\newlength\maxfnwidth
  \fi
}

% \newfnwidth{N}{W}
% is read from aux file
% sets \maxfnwidth-N to the maximum of W and \maxfnwidth-N
\newcommand\newfnwidth[2]{%
  \ensuredefmaxfnwidth{#1}%
  \ifdim\maxfnwidth<#2
     \global\maxfnwidth=#2
  \fi
}

% \fnwidth{footnote mark}
% writes the command "\newfnwidth{\idfnwidth}{width of footnote mark}"
% to the aux file
\newlength\thisfnwidth
\newcommand\fnwidth[1]{%
  \settowidth\thisfnwidth{#1}%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newfnwidth{\idfnwidth}{\the\thisfnwidth}}%
}

% \@makefntext{footnote text}
% Writes the width of the footnote mark to the aux file
% and typesets the footnote
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \fnwidth{\@thefnmark}%
  \makebox[\maxfnwidth][r]{\@thefnmark}.\enspace#1%
}

% initialize \idfnwidth and \maxfnwidth-0
\ensuredefmaxfnwidth{0}

% counter for identifying minipages
\newcounter{fnwidth}

% at the beginning of each minipage, increment the counter
% and initialize \maxfnwidth
\AtBeginEnvironment{minipage}{%
  \stepcounter{fnwidth}%
  \ensuredefmaxfnwidth{\arabic{fnwidth}}%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@symbolesnum[1]{% new numerotation for minipage footnote
    \ifcase#1\unskip \or \unskip * \or \unskip † \or \unskip ‡ \or \unskip ** \or \unskip †† \or \unskip ‡‡ \or \unskip *** \or \unskip ††† \or \unskip ‡‡‡ \or \unskip **** \or \unskip †††† \or \unskip ‡‡‡‡ \or \unskip ***** \or \unskip ††††† \or \unskip ‡‡‡‡‡ \else\@ctrerr \fi
}
\def\thempfootnote{\@symbolesnum{\c@mpfootnote}}

% maximal length of footnote label
% assumes that \idfnwidth is set to a value identifying the context
% (0 = outside minipage, 1,2,3,... inside minipage)
% Depending on \idfnwidth, \maxfnwidth expands to the macro name
% \maxfnwidth-0, \maxfnwidth-1, \maxfnwidth-2, ...
\newcommand\maxfnwidth{\csname maxfnwidth-\idfnwidth\endcsname}

% \ensuredefmaxfnwidth{N}
% set \idfnwidth to N and define the length \maxfnwidth-N (if undefined)
\newcommand\ensuredefmaxfnwidth[1]{%
  \edef\idfnwidth{#1}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\maxfnwidth\relax
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\newlength\maxfnwidth
  \fi
}

% \newfnwidth{N}{W}
% read from aux file
% sets \maxfnwidth-N to the maximum of W and \maxfnwidth-N
\newcommand\newfnwidth[2]{%
  \ensuredefmaxfnwidth{#1}%
  \ifdim\maxfnwidth<#2
     \global\maxfnwidth=#2
  \fi
}

% \fnwidth{footnote mark}
% writes the command "\newfnwidth{\idfnwidth}{width of footnote mark}"
% to the aux file
\newlength\thisfnwidth
\newcommand\fnwidth[1]{%
  \settowidth\thisfnwidth{#1}%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newfnwidth{\idfnwidth}{\the\thisfnwidth}}%
}

% \@makefntext{footnote text}
% Writes the width of the footnote mark to the aux file
% and typesets the footnote
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \fnwidth{\@thefnmark}%
  \makebox[\maxfnwidth][r]{\@thefnmark}.\enspace#1%
}

% initialize \idfnwidth and \maxfnwidth-0
\ensuredefmaxfnwidth{0}

% counter for identifying minipages
\newcounter{fnwidth}

% at the beginning of each minipage, increment the counter
% and initialize \maxfnwidth
\AtBeginEnvironment{minipage}{%
  \stepcounter{fnwidth}%
  \ensuredefmaxfnwidth{\arabic{fnwidth}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\footnote{A footnote.},
consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ornare, risus sit amet lacinia lacinia, lacus erat tristique est, et consequat nunc dolor id lorem. Suspendisse lobortis, metus vitae semper volutpat, nulla metus mollis tortor, non finibus sem quam id mauris\footnote{A footnote.}. Fusce ut velit ac magna aliquet ullamcorper vitae nec massa. Nunc suscipit ipsum tortor, sed facilisis nisi ultrices finibus. Cras efficitur felis felis, sit amet aliquam dolor posuere et. Curabitur ut condimentum lorem. Etiam ac nisi augue. Nullam congue purus et metus fringilla malesuada. Praesent faucibus fermentum mi eget fringilla. Morbi velit ipsum, lacinia sed dolor id, fermentum auctor velit\footnote{A footnote.}. Donec quis ante eget enim tempor ultrices.

Pellentesque ultrices efficitur ipsum ut bibendum. Sed ut vestibulum mi. Sed neque neque, efficitur nec sem eget, pulvinar ultricies lectus. Nam ullamcorper dolor sed nulla ultricies varius. Donec mattis cursus dolor eu vehicula. Fusce molestie at ipsum vel commodo\footnote{A footnote.}. Vivamus eu malesuada metus. Praesent sed cursus ex. Fusce justo eros, elementum quis libero et, vestibulum pretium tortor. In rhoncus ex eu posuere placerat. Aenean fringilla sem a nisi aliquet egestas\footnote{A footnote.}. Fusce vestibulum leo nibh, vel sollicitudin mauris interdum sed.

Curabitur tincidunt augue et rutrum laoreet. Morbi pharetra lacus ac mi finibus condimentum. Nunc id venenatis neque. Fusce sed purus quis magna accumsan euismod a ac augue. Integer venenatis vulputate lacus, vel dapibus augue hendrerit sed\footnote{A footnote.}. Donec eget mattis arcu, nec hendrerit ante. Donec rutrum est ut massa blandit, id semper metus tincidunt. Suspendisse nec vulputate risus, nec efficitur ex. Donec condimentum risus ligula, at consectetur erat lacinia sed. Aenean vel euismod purus. Vestibulum interdum neque vitae erat rhoncus fermentum. Aenean convallis nisl velit, sit amet volutpat dui vulputate a.

Sed nec augue pellentesque, commodo diam quis, vehicula libero\footnote{A footnote.}. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus tincidunt ligula vitae arcu tempor, eu facilisis augue fringilla. Curabitur id pulvinar ipsum, et gravida nisl. Aenean eget faucibus dolor, vel fermentum metus\footnote{A footnote.}. Quisque risus purus, porta vel eleifend nec, tempus sit amet diam. Sed sit amet commodo odio. Curabitur in tempor lorem. Sed venenatis malesuada odio, ac scelerisque nisi finibus ac. Aliquam cursus aliquet eleifend.

Duis in nisi vitae augue lacinia sodales sed vel libero. Duis vehicula, justo commodo ultrices blandit, purus sem ultrices velit, in imperdiet ligula sem vel sem\footnote{A footnote.}. Nam diam turpis, pulvinar ac lorem at, sagittis cursus nibh. Sed id gravida enim, id rutrum felis. Nam aliquet leo vel venenatis volutpat. Integer laoreet tincidunt mi, in faucibus nunc. Fusce porta et lorem id consectetur. Praesent ac vehicula metus, quis hendrerit tellus\footnote{A footnote.}. Maecenas consequat eleifend ante, non vehicula risus aliquet vitae. Duis et velit elit. Mauris nec lorem vel lorem rhoncus congue vitae in arcu.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\footnote{A footnote.}, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ornare, risus sit amet lacinia lacinia, lacus erat tristique est, et consequat nunc dolor id lorem. Suspendisse lobortis, metus vitae semper volutpat, nulla metus mollis tortor, non finibus sem quam id mauris\footnote{A footnote.}. Fusce ut velit ac magna aliquet ullamcorper vitae nec massa. Nunc suscipit ipsum tortor, sed facilisis nisi ultrices finibus. Cras efficitur felis felis, sit amet aliquam dolor posuere et. Curabitur ut condimentum lorem. Etiam ac nisi augue. Nullam congue purus et metus fringilla malesuada. Praesent faucibus fermentum mi eget fringilla. Morbi velit ipsum, lacinia sed dolor id, fermentum auctor velit\footnote{A footnote.}. Donec quis ante eget enim tempor ultrices.

Pellentesque ultrices efficitur ipsum ut bibendum. Sed ut vestibulum mi. Sed neque neque, efficitur nec sem eget, pulvinar ultricies lectus. Nam ullamcorper dolor sed nulla ultricies varius. Donec mattis cursus dolor eu vehicula. Fusce molestie at ipsum vel commodo\footnote{A footnote.}. Vivamus eu malesuada metus. Praesent sed cursus ex. Fusce justo eros, elementum quis libero et, vestibulum pretium tortor. In rhoncus ex eu posuere placerat. Aenean fringilla sem a nisi aliquet egestas\footnote{A footnote.}. Fusce vestibulum leo nibh, vel sollicitudin mauris interdum sed.

Curabitur tincidunt augue et rutrum laoreet. Morbi pharetra lacus ac mi finibus condimentum. Nunc id venenatis neque. Fusce sed purus quis magna accumsan euismod a ac augue. Integer venenatis vulputate lacus, vel dapibus augue hendrerit sed\footnote{A footnote.}. Donec eget mattis arcu, nec hendrerit ante. Donec rutrum est ut massa blandit, id semper metus tincidunt. Suspendisse nec vulputate risus, nec efficitur ex. Donec condimentum risus ligula, at consectetur erat lacinia sed. Aenean vel euismod purus. Vestibulum interdum neque vitae erat rhoncus fermentum. Aenean convallis nisl velit, sit amet volutpat dui vulputate a.

Sed nec augue pellentesque, commodo diam quis, vehicula libero\footnote{A footnote.}. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus tincidunt ligula vitae arcu tempor, eu facilisis augue fringilla. Curabitur id pulvinar ipsum, et gravida nisl. Aenean eget faucibus dolor, vel fermentum metus\footnote{A footnote.}. Quisque risus purus, porta vel eleifend nec, tempus sit amet diam. Sed sit amet commodo odio. Curabitur in tempor lorem. Sed venenatis malesuada odio, ac scelerisque nisi finibus ac. Aliquam cursus aliquet eleifend.

Duis in nisi vitae augue lacinia sodales sed vel libero. Duis vehicula, justo commodo ultrices blandit, purus sem ultrices velit, in imperdiet ligula sem vel sem\footnote{A footnote.}. Nam diam turpis, pulvinar ac lorem at, sagittis cursus nibh. Sed id gravida enim, id rutrum felis. Nam aliquet leo vel venenatis volutpat. Integer laoreet tincidunt mi, in faucibus nunc. Fusce porta et lorem id consectetur. Praesent ac vehicula metus, quis hendrerit tellus\footnote{A footnote.}. Maecenas consequat eleifend ante, non vehicula risus aliquet vitae. Duis et velit elit. Mauris nec lorem vel lorem rhoncus congue vitae in arcu.

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm}%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ornare, risus sit amet lacinia lacinia, lacus erat tristique est, et consequat nunc dolor id lorem. Suspendisse lobortis, metus vitae semper volutpat, nulla metus mollis tortor, non finibus sem quam id mauris. Fusce ut velit ac magna aliquet ullamcorper vitae nec massa. Nunc suscipit ipsum tortor, sed facilisis nisi ultrices finibus\footnote{A footnote.}. Cras efficitur felis felis, sit amet aliquam dolor posuere et. Curabitur ut condimentum lorem. Etiam ac nisi augue. Nullam congue purus et metus fringilla malesuada. Praesent faucibus fermentum mi eget fringilla. Morbi velit ipsum, lacinia sed dolor id, fermentum auctor velit. Donec quis ante eget enim tempor ultrices.

Pellentesque ultrices efficitur ipsum ut bibendum. Sed ut vestibulum mi. Sed neque neque, efficitur nec sem eget, pulvinar ultricies lectus. Nam ullamcorper dolor sed nulla ultricies varius. Donec mattis cursus dolor eu vehicula. Fusce molestie at ipsum vel commodo\footnote{A footnote.}. Vivamus eu malesuada metus. Praesent sed cursus ex. Fusce justo eros, elementum quis libero et, vestibulum pretium tortor. In rhoncus ex eu posuere placerat. Aenean fringilla sem a nisi aliquet egestas. Fusce vestibulum leo nibh, vel sollicitudin mauris interdum sed.

Curabitur tincidunt augue et rutrum laoreet. Morbi pharetra lacus ac mi finibus condimentum. Nunc id venenatis neque. Fusce sed purus quis magna accumsan euismod a ac augue. Integer venenatis vulputate lacus, vel dapibus augue hendrerit sed. Donec eget mattis arcu, nec hendrerit ante. Donec rutrum est ut massa blandit, id semper metus tincidunt. Suspendisse nec vulputate risus, nec efficitur ex. Donec condimentum risus ligula, at consectetur erat lacinia sed. Aenean vel euismod purus. Vestibulum interdum neque vitae erat rhoncus fermentum. Aenean convallis nisl velit, sit amet volutpat dui vulputate a.
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm}%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ornare, risus sit amet lacinia lacinia, lacus erat tristique est, et consequat nunc dolor id lorem. Suspendisse lobortis, metus vitae semper volutpat, nulla metus mollis tortor, non finibus sem quam id mauris. Fusce ut velit ac magna aliquet ullamcorper vitae nec massa\footnote{A footnote.}. Nunc suscipit ipsum tortor, sed facilisis nisi ultrices finibus\footnote{A footnote.}. Cras efficitur felis felis, sit amet aliquam dolor posuere et. Curabitur ut condimentum lorem. Etiam ac nisi augue. Nullam congue purus et metus fringilla malesuada. Praesent faucibus fermentum mi eget fringilla. Morbi velit ipsum, lacinia sed dolor id, fermentum auctor velit. Donec quis ante eget enim tempor ultrices.

Pellentesque ultrices efficitur ipsum ut bibendum. Sed ut vestibulum mi. Sed neque neque, efficitur nec sem eget, pulvinar ultricies lectus\footnote{A footnote.}. Nam ullamcorper dolor sed nulla ultricies varius. Donec mattis cursus dolor eu vehicula. Fusce molestie at ipsum vel commodo\footnote{A footnote.}. Vivamus eu malesuada metus. Praesent sed cursus ex. Fusce justo eros, elementum quis libero et, vestibulum pretium tortor. In rhoncus ex eu posuere placerat. Aenean fringilla sem a nisi aliquet egestas. Fusce vestibulum leo nibh, vel sollicitudin mauris interdum sed.

Curabitur tincidunt augue et rutrum laoreet\footnote{A footnote.}. Morbi pharetra lacus ac mi finibus condimentum. Nunc id venenatis neque. Fusce sed purus quis magna accumsan euismod a ac augue. Integer venenatis vulputate lacus, vel dapibus augue hendrerit sed. Donec eget mattis arcu, nec hendrerit ante. Donec rutrum est ut massa blandit, id semper metus tincidunt. Suspendisse nec vulputate risus, nec efficitur ex. Donec condimentum risus ligula, at consectetur erat lacinia sed\footnote{A footnote.}. Aenean vel euismod purus. Vestibulum interdum neque vitae erat rhoncus fermentum. Aenean convallis nisl velit, sit amet volutpat dui vulputate a\footnote{A footnote.}.
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```